# Boot-Repair failed. Need help plz

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, kubuntu, boot-repair

pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d5VwhsBvwY/

I bought a new SSD planning to run only kubuntu for my laptop. I was having both kubuntu and Windows 10 sitting in one drive. Booting in legacy mode goes directly into kubuntu. Booting in UEFI goes into Windows 10.(I think I did something wrong installing the kubuntu with legacy boot, my bad).

I cloned kubuntu partition into the new SSD. It went smoothly. Now I need to fix the boot issue. I want it to use UEFI boot. However, now I stuck with both boot modes not working.

Help please. I'm pretty noob with ubuntu/linux. I'm using this laptop for just about a month. If a correct reinstall of kubuntu is right way to go then so be it. Thank you.

Edit:
**Problem solved!** I ran Boot-Repair again with UEFI boot mode. This time Boot-Repair told me I'm missing a 250mb FAT32 EFI boot partition instead of a 20mb un-formated partition for legacy boot. So I created a new partition and successfully boot into my old Kubuntu! Thanks Boot-Repair~ Thanks Ubuntu community~

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I ran Boot-Repair again with UEFI boot mode. This time Boot-Repair told me I'm missing a 250mb FAT32 EFI boot partition instead of a 20mb un-formated partition for legacy boot. So I created a new partition and successfully boot into my old Kubuntu! Thanks Boot-Repair~ Thanks Ubuntu community~